# Visual Studio 2015 Auto Build

Tags: visual-studio

I noticed that my app does not build automatically anymore: Is this new behaviour?
Have I a setting which is incorrect?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
```

The project builds when I fix errors but error fixes are updated automatically in the error window.

Comment: What  do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: If I made a change to my code which resulted in an error this would be reflected in the error window but this is not happening now - or if I corrected an error in code the error window is not updated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?  If that doesn't fix it, see if the `Build` > `Clean Solution` menu item helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you able to build the solution with the appropriate menu item?  Does it  correctly update the list of errors?

Comment: Corrected error disappear when app is built.

Comment: Have you set the error list filter to Build only? (error list filtering is new in VS 2015)

Comment: You are correct sir ! Error window to Build + Intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Error window to Build + IntelliSense.